# Download sql lite database from Google Drive

Tags: react-native, sqlite, mobile, google-drive-api

I am developing a project in react native expo and I have inserted a function that allows you to upload the sql lite database, which contains the user's data, to the user's Google Drive through the google drive api. The file is loaded correctly so now I need to create another function that allows you to load the database on Google Drive to replace it with the current one.

How can I download database from Google Drive using google drive api?